# Javascript: Remove all event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the best way to remove all event listeners? I've got something like this (using jQuery) but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it:

```
// Remove all the event listernes
$('*').off('blur click change dblclick each error focus focusin focusout keydown keypress keyup load mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave popstate resize scroll select submit unload');
$(window).off('scroll');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("body").find("*").off();
```

this would remove all event listeners on all elements within the body

Comment: Does this also remove all events bound on the window-object? If not, is it a simple $(window).off(); So the final code to remove all event listeners is: $("body").find("*").off(); $(window).off();

Comment: this removes all events bound to objects in the body, but not the window. and yes $(window).off() would remove those bound to the window. the $(selector).off() function removes all event listeners on the selected item/items. in my answer, off() was called on $(body).find("*"), which means all children of body.

Answer (score 0):

Does .unbind() not do the trick?

E.g.:

```js
$("#click_for_hello").on("click",function(){
 alert("hello");
})
$("#click_for_hello").unbind();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click_for_hello">Click me</button>
```

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, unbind() has been deprecated, it's recommended to use .off() instead which does the same thing as unbind(): http://api.jquery.com/unbind/#entry-longdesc

My example above works, but I think off() and unbind() is more designed to remove an event listener from a single element as you demonstrated. Because I want to remove all event listeners from every element an event listener was added to, I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do it than in my example.

Comment: I'll test rakan316's solution.